# Javascript textbox validation not working?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to sort this out for most of the day yesterday with no luck - I'm quite new to Javascript so bear with me. I'm trying to create a questionnaire as part of a project that I have been asked to do.

I have the following code which creates a set number of textboxes for the user to enter questions in - they choose how many textboxes / questions they wish to create. This is the code that performs the textbox creation and passes the number of questions that the user wishes to create to Javascript:

```
     <?php
       //Loop for question textboxes
       for ( $i = 1; $i <= intval($_SESSION['Questions']); $i++ ) { 
         echo"
           <b>Question ". $i  ."</b><br>
           <input type='text' style='width: 42em;' name='box{$i}' id='box{$i}'>
           <br><br>
         "; 
       }
       echo'
         <br>
         <input type='.Submit.'>
         <br><br>
       ';              

     ?>

     <script>
       var Questions = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['Questions']); ?>;
     </script>
```

And then on form submission:

```
function QuestionsValidation(f) {

        var msg = "";

        for (i = 1; i <= Questions; i++) {
          if (f.box+i.value == "") {
              msg += "Question" +i "empty!\n";                
          }
        }

        if (msg !== "") {
            alert ("Errors in form:\n" + msg);
          return false;
        }

        else {
          return true;
        }
}
```

I'm almost certain that the reason for it not working is in the IF statement inside the javascript For loop, but I appreciate any suggestions. I removed the IF statement inside the For loop and replaced it with:

```
        for (i = 1; i <= Questions; i++) {
          msg += f.box+i.value;                
        }
```

to try and source the problem.. It returns NaN?

Comment: What is being passed to the QuestionsValidation function in the f category. Are you using a javascript library like jquery?

Comment: I haven't touched jquery, I have had a lot of success so far without touching it so thought I could cope with this without going into it. I have a form which is this:    <form action = 'Createquestions.php' method = 'post' onsubmit='return QuestionsValidation(this)'>

Answer (score 0):

When creating text boxes through loop, add a class for every textbox like

```
<input type='text' class='question' style='width: 42em;' name='box{$i}' id='box{$i}'>
```

On submit button, call validateQuestions() function like

```
<input type='submit' onclick='return validateQuestions();' value='Submit' />
```

Write following jQuery code

```
$(function(){
function validateQuestions(){
     $('.question').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val()==''){
            alert('Question is required.'); // or write error msg in a div
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
     })
}        
})
```

Note: try to read jQuery Validation plugin as well.

Hope this helps !